# getting a 400 status when doing a patch request with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest, axios

I'm building a front end with react and one of the components needs to take accept a patch request to increment or decrement the vote.

Can anybody spot a reason why I might be getting a 400 for this code.

```
handleIncrementVote = () => {
    const { commentid, articleid } = this.state;

    const vote = {
        inc_votes: this.state.votes
    }

    axios.patch(`https://lloyd- 
   news.herokuapp.com/api/articles/${articleid}/comments/${commentid}`, 
   { 
   vote })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            inc_votes: prevState.votes + 1
        }), () => {
            console.log(this.state.votes)
        })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

When I send the request with postman it works fine. Any ideas? Does my syntax look ok?

Comment: What request exactly are you sending with postman? What does the network panel in your devtools show?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in dev tools to ensure your request matches the request you make in Postman?

Comment: ok so I'm getting a 204 no content before it becomes a 400

Comment: That's most likely the options request you're seeing that is returning a 204. Can you post the body of the `patch` request?

Comment: in postman the body is {
 "inc_votes": 5
} which is working

Comment: Hi Hemadri, I tried just passing in vote instead of { vote } but that doesnt seem to solve it

Comment: hi stever it is on one line in my code. it just split up in stack overflow but its correct in vs code

Comment: I tried and it doesnt change... That is just the way stackoverflow put it. On vs code it is on one line already but thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My bad! I was passing in this.props rather than this.state in my object. Thanks for everyones suggestions!